# What does 稀な公募 mean?

Tags: translation, nuances, set-phrases, business-japanese

I am translating a personal statement and when talking about his work experience, the writer has stated 私は、役所の人事としては稀な公募によって、広く民間企業からの採用を行うこととした。しかし、同時に、公募を行うと、採用実績のない民間企業から採用する可能性もあり、能力の低い職員を採用してしまう危険性もあった。

Is it saying that 'he implemented a system by which people from the wider private sector are recruited in selective public recruitment'. Does this mean the job is advertised widely?

Also I don't understand 採用実績のない民間企業. How can a company have no record of hiring people?

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a parsing issue here.

It is not 「（稀{まれ}な公募{こうぼ}）によって」.

It is 「役所{やくしょ}の人事{じんじ}としては稀な（、）『公募』によって」.

≒ 「『公募』という方法{ほうほう}によって」

> Does this mean the job is advertised widely?

At least "publicly" so, if not so "widely".  How widely, we could not tell from this passage alone.

The speaker utilized a method that was 稀な ("rare, uncommon") for the city hall to recruit.

> Also I don't understand 採用実績{さいようじっせき}のない民間企業{みんかんきぎょう}. How can a company have no record of hiring people?

Again, a parsing error.

It means "**the private companies from which the city hall has never recruited people**".  It is saying (or implying) that if you advertize the position openings too widely, you might end up hiring untalented people.

Comment: Thanks so much!  I think I was just so deep in it (and had convinced myself of a different meaning), that I was lost.

Answer (score 0):

私は、役所の人事としては稀な公募によって、広く民間企業からの採用を行うこととした。しかし、同時に、公募を行うと、採用実績のない民間企業から採用する可能性もあり、能力の低い職員を採用してしまう危険性もあった。

役所 is a bit ambiguous in the sentence. I adopted government office. 
So, he decided to implement unusual/rare job offer for government office to recruit a personnel from private sector.

稀な公募 is the job offering to private sector is uncommon for the office.

採用実績のない民間企業.  implies recruiting personnels from private companies which has no track records for the goverment office.